# how to prevent cron logs from registering in syslog?

Tags: logging, cron, rsyslog

I have separated my crontab logging into `/var/log/cron.log` by uncommenting the below line in `/etc/syslog.conf`, but it still writes to `/var/log/syslog` too!

```
cron.*                                  /var/log/cron.log
```

How can i prevent it from writing to `/var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to find the line that defines what should be sent to /var/log/syslog and modify it so that cron messages are not included. For example on an Ubuntu system I have to hand the `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file has the following entry for syslog:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none             -/var/log/syslog
```

changing it to:

```
*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none             -/var/log/syslog
```

Does what you want. Note that the above is taking advantage of the ability to specify multiple facilities with the same priority as a list, if you don't already have a `.none` priority you would have to do this for example:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.info;cron.none             -/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you to describe more the second part of your answer?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me :( even with restarting rsyslog and cron

Answer (score -2):

add

```
cron.none             -/var/log/syslog
```

in your syslog.conf